# QT: unit-testing segmentation fault

Tags: unit-testing, qt, user-interface, segmentation-fault, qtestlib

Below is a code block for simulating key presses on a menu. I can navigate deep into the menus of my application but when I get back to the main form, I'm getting a segmetation error.... :(

first I show my Application:

```
std::auto_ptr<MyForm> mainForm( new MyForm( 3, 3 ));
mainForm->show();
```

Then simulate a keyPress to show the main menu:

```
QTest::keyPress(mainForm.get(), Qt::Key_0, NULL, 300);
QTest::keyRelease(mainForm.get(), Qt::Key_0, NULL, 300);
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QCOMPARE(QString(pWin->objectName()), QString("MainMenu"));
```

Then simulate another keyPress to go back to my main application:

```
QTest::keyPress(pWin, Qt::Key_Escape, NULL, 300);
QTest::keyRelease(pWin, Qt::Key_Escape, NULL, 300);
pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QCOMPARE(QString(pWin->objectName()), QString("MainForm"));
```

This is where I'm getting the segmentation fault... Can anybody tell me what's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with checking the result of `QApplication::activeWindow()`. From the docs..

> Returns the application top-level
>   window that has the keyboard input
>   focus, or 0 if no application window
>   has the focus. There might be an
>   activeWindow() even if there is no
>   focusWidget(), for example if no
>   widget in that window accepts key
>   events.